# Can’t get it all put together

Tags: brushless-motor, electronics, rcservo

I’m building a small hobby robot- here’s the parts I’ve got:

- 3 x 5 V brushless DC motors
- 3 x ESCs
- 3 digital voltage regulators
- RC MC6C transceiver
- 1 x 5 V battery
- 1 x 12 V battery
- WAGO Clip thingies

Help! How do I make the motors run? (Trying to avoid Arduino or RPi)
I’m decently new to all this so detailed help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: the parts you have will build a remotely controlled vehicle, not a robot

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a good datasheet for your RC setup, but the receiver should have servo/PWM outputs. The ESC should have a brown/red/orange connector that plugs into the receiver. Receiver channels should correspond to the transmitter channels.

**Be sure you are using appropriate batteries** so you don't exceed the voltage limits for your devices.

Attach the motors to the ESC motor outputs, power everything on, and run the motor. You might be able to power the receiver from the ESC if it has a "battery eliminator circuit" (BEC), otherwise you'll almost certainly need a battery with a different voltage for the ESC and the receiver.

**Be sure you are using appropriate batteries.** When in doubt, read the datasheet.

You should have an arrangement that looks like the picture below, which is taken from [this website](https://www.rcpano.net/2023/02/19/what-is-the-rc-esc-what-is-bec-ubec-what-does-bec-ubec-do/):

[image: circuit layout]